# bootstrap-switch functionality does not load when I re-render a partial with "respond_do"

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, twitter-bootstrap

I use [bootstrap-switch](https://github.com/nostalgiaz/bootstrap-switch) and I've implemented it with [bootstrap-switch-rails](https://github.com/manuelvanrijn/bootstrap-switch-rails). Awesome feature, but I am having problems with its persistance when using an ajax response to render a partial with it.

I have a view file:

```
#### index.html.haml

#partial_id= render 'partial'
```

that renders a partial (containing a bootstrap-switch toggle function and a clickable button):

```
#### _partial.html.haml

.switch{"data-off-label" => "OFF", "data-on-label" => "ON"}
  %input{:checked => "", :type => "checkbox"}

%button.click-here
```

When the click-here buttton is clicked, an ajax get request is triggered:

```
#### some_script.js.coffee

btn = $("#click-here")
btn.off "click"
btn.click (e) ->

  $.ajax
    type: "get"
    dataType: "script"
    url: "some_controller/some_action"
```

A controller picks up the request:

```
#### some_controller.rb

def some_action
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js
  end
end
```

and responds with:

```
#### some_action.js.erb

var partial = $("#partial_id");
partial.children().remove();
partial.append('<%= j render("partial") %>');
```

When the partial gets re-rendered the script/stylesheet from bootstrap-switch does not get loaded (or something like that), because instead of the toggle function a simple check box is shown. How can this be?

Comment: Same issue here with ASP.Net 4.5, using a switch an <asp:UpdatePanel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not technically the same item that you attached to earlier, as you have replaced it in your js.erb response. You just need to let the javascript pick up the new item. Adding `$('.switch')['bootstrapSwitch']();` to the end of your `some_action.js.erb` file should do the trick....