# How to use javascript functions within ajaxified partials?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In a Rails 3.2 app I have a javascript function that is triggered by the presence of a DOM element with class "trigger". (this function adds UI elements).

This works perfectly, except in partials that are rendered by ajax calls.

For example in an index view, when the page is initially rendered the function is correctly called and the UI elements rendered.

If the user then filters or paginates or otherwise interacts with the index via ajax, the function is not called and the UI elements are not applied when the partial is re-rendered via the ajax call.

So, how can I make javascript aware of elements that are rendered via ajax calls?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems this question has been asked before, but I was not using the correct search terms.

In case anyone else stumbles across this, the answer is...

Adding `$('.switch')['bootstrapSwitch']();` to the end of your `some_action.js.erb` file should do the trick....

And the full question is

[bootstrap-switch functionality does not load when I re-render a partial with "respond_do"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16385608/bootstrap-switch-functionality-does-not-load-when-i-re-render-a-partial-with-re)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use [jQuery.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method.

eg

```
$("#content").on("click", "input[type='checkbox']", function(event){
  // do some stuff
});
```